# negation of an advance conditional statement

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

If f is continuous on a closed interval [a, b] and differentiable on the
open interval (a, b) and if f'(x) > 0 for every x ∈ (a, b), then f is increasing on [a, b].

I was giving the logical statement above and asked to negate it. I know its a conditional statement which means its negation is p∧¬q, but there are logical and's in the "p" part of the statement. Do I have to negate those and's as well?

My answer, which was wrong, was as follows

If there exists a function f that is either continuous or differentiable on the interval I or if f'(x) > 0 for every x ∈ (a, b) and f is not increasing on I.

Comment: "There is a function $f$ that is continuous (on $[a,b]$) and differentiable (on $(a,b)$) such that $f'(x) >0$ for every $x \in (a,b)$ and $f$ is **not**-increasing (on $[a,b]$)".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with your answer:

Let,
A be "f is continuous on a closed interval [a, b]"

B be "differentiable on the open interval (a, b)"

C be "f'(x) > 0 for every x ∈ (a, b)"

D be "f is increasing on [a, b]."

The statement says:

$$(A \wedge B \wedge C) \rightarrow D$$

It's negation is:

$$(A \wedge B \wedge C) \wedge \neg D$$

Negation:

f is continuous on a closed interval [a, b] and differentiable on the open interval (a, b) and if f'(x) > 0 for every x ∈ (a, b) and f is not increasing on [a, b].

Comment: You also need to account for the quantifiers.  "If $f$ is continuous..." really means "for every $f$, if $f$ is continuous..."

Comment: Yes, but I just used what the asker had given me. I decided to do the negation of a logical statement rather than use the maths behind it.